# Are measure on Poisson random variable and exponential random variable atomic?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

We have the following random variables:

1) $P(X=k)= \dfrac{\lambda^k e^{-k}}{k!}$

2) $P(X \le x)= 1 -  e^{-( x  - t)}$ for $t\ge0$

3) $P(X\le x)={x^2}1_{(0,1/2)}(x) + {1 \over 2}1_{(1/2,2)}(x) + 1_{[2, \infty)}(x)$

In the first case random variable for sure has atomic measure, because it's discrete distribution and the smallest measure singleton

In the second and third cases r.v doesn't have atomic measure, because the measure is defined on interval ($R$) and we can find always interval, that has less measure (because $R$ is complete)

But how can we show it more formally?

Comment: Are you sure about your answer for (3)?

Comment: @kimchilover Why am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know if you are wrong. In case (3), is the function $P(X\le x)$ continuous?  OR: what is your definition of "atomic measure"?  Does it mean, there exist atoms, or does it mean all the measure is atoms?

Comment: @kimchilover it means, if the following r.v have atomic measure

Comment: Yes, of course, but what is an "atomic measure"?  A measure with an atom, (that is, not non-atomic) or a measure all of whose mass is in atoms? While you are at it, how about telling me if in (3), the function $P(X\le t)$ is continuous?

Comment: @kimchilover atomic measure is measure that has atoms. And in (3) function is not continious everywhere, because it has discontinuity at 2

Comment: So doesn't that make (3) atomic, with atoms  $\{1/2\}$  (which I think you overlooked) and $\{2\}$ ?

Comment: $\#2$ would make sense if you said "for $x\ge t.$" $\qquad$

Comment: @kimchilover exactly! Thank you:)

Comment: @MichaelHardy no, it makes not sense.

Comment: @kimchilover : The word "atomless" is far better than "non-atomic" because "non-atomic" can easily be mistaken for "not atomic".

Comment: If I used any of these terms in a paper I would instantly gloss them with a short definition to eliminate this kind of confusion.  Bogachev's book defines "purely atomic" and "atomless" on the page pointed to by the index entry for "atomic measure" which he does not define.

Comment: @kimchilover But how can make my arguments more formally?

Comment: First, by being crystal clear what you mean by *atomic measure*, which is not a standard term and ambiguous.  This is important, because it determines what you are trying to prove.  If you can't state your result clearly & unambiguously, you can't make a valid proof. Second, by identifying the atoms, by checking for discontinuities  of the distribution function or otherwise.  Finally, by clearly stating what's what, and why.